# Unable to set selected option in dropdown control

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am unable to bind selected option in dropdown control. I don't want whole object of `$scope.Types` inside `$scope.obj`. It should just have **value** of `$scope.Types` inside `$scope.obj.type`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
   $scope.types =
        [
            { label: "Pizza", value: 1 },
            { label: "Cakes", value: 2 },
            { label: "Pastry", value: 3 }
        ];
        
         $scope.obj = { type : 1 };//I want dropdown selected value to be updated in type variable
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
 <select name="status" ng-model="obj.value"
 ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in types track by type.value">
       <option value="">Select Types</option>
</select>
 </ul>
```

I am not getting what wrong I am doing here.

Answer (score 2):

```js
 var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {

   $scope.obj = {};
   $scope.types =
        [
            { label: "Pizza", value: 1 },
            { label: "Cakes", value: 2 },
            { label: "Pastry", value: 3 }
        ];
         
         $scope.obj.value = 2;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
 <select name="status" ng-model="obj.value"
 ng-options="type.value as type.label for type in types">
       <option value="">Select Types</option>
</select>
 </ul>
```

Comment: i am updating everything in sometimes, it is working for me

Comment: Can u please Copy and paste above code to notepad, and put js Code inside the Script tag and Run. I am not aware about the "RUN CODE SNIPPET" how it works.

Comment: i have updated the code snippet, it is working now with "RUN CODE SNIPPET".

Comment: When i add track by option at the end then it is not working.Can you please tell me why?

Comment: Please read the AngularJS Documentation, it explained very well.https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
   
   $scope.$watch('selectedValue', function(newValue, oldValue) {
        if (newValue){
            $scope.obj.type = newValue.value;
        }
   });
   $scope.types =
        [
            { label: "Pizza", value: 1 },
            { label: "Cakes", value: 2 },
            { label: "Pastry", value: 3 }
        ];
   $scope.obj = { type: 1 };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">
 <select name="status" ng-model="selectedValue"
 ng-options="type as type.label for type in types track by type.value">
       <option value="">Select Types</option>
</select>
{{ obj.type}}
 </ul>
```

Comment: I want to show label(pizza,cakes,pastry) in my dropdown instread of 1,2,3 which are values

Comment: Still there is a problem when i select Pizza from dropdown.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Try selecting Pizza from drodown it wont allow you to select it

Comment: Updated. Try again.

Comment: But by Default If i have set $scope.obj = { type : 1 }; then why pizza is not getting selected automatically for the first time?

Comment: so is it that your question is to set the default to the select?

Comment: Yes so actually based on existing value I would like dropdown to have selected value

Comment: Here I edited the answer. Hope this is the final version.

Comment: Now it is working but this will required changes in my structure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184621/discussion-between-learning-overthinker-confused-and-holydragon).

Comment: Updated. Let's see if this is what you are looking for.